java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter
I have a Spring Boot project that fails on startup.
Error log:
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [expedia.content.solutions.metrics.spring.RegisterMetricsPostProcessorConfig] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@c387f44]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:320)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:413)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:336)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:246)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:534)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2676)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 36 common frames omitted

I have tried to use OpenRewrite script as well to fix the above problem but it's not getting resolved.
My pom.xml:
    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <relativePath/>
        </parent>
         <properties>
            <java.version>21</java.version>
       
    <spring-boot-admin-client.version>2.0.0</spring-boot-admin-client.version>
     </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
    
                <!-- Spring cloud -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>2022.0.5</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
  </dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>

Please let me know if any dependency need to be added or any conflicts
Let me know if any further details needed.

used this also
https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/framework/migratehandlerinterceptor
